# How to force Google Sign-In to launch account manager in browser itself instead of launching android's account manager

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-signin

I'm developing a website for the people of an organization which uses G-Suite and the admin of the G-Suite requires users to install some annoying apps so no one wants to add their official account on their Android device.

I integrated Google Sign-In on my site so that I can identify someone in the organization from others.

But now the problem is when the user clicks on the "Sign-In" button on the chrome the **account manager*** of the android gets launched if you are signed into the chrome and asks you to add the account to the android.

So is there a way to launch the **normal accounts page by google***  that opens usually on the desktop and also on the android chrome when a user isn't logged into the chrome?

***By Account manager I meant [This image(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InDwa.png).**
***By normal accounts page by google I meant [This image(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1bqf.png).**
***By "chrome" I mean "Google Chrome on Android"**

Comment: Were you ever be able to solve this?

Comment: @M66B, Seems Google don't want you to login on chrome but not on device.